# UIActivityIndicatorView not showing in webview

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a UINavigationController that I am adding a UIViewController to. Inside my UIViewController I have a webview and also trying to set a UIActivityIndicatorView. However I can't seem to get the UIActivityIndicatorView to show up. Any help would be great!

```
class TestWebViewController: UIViewController {

    var loadSpinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    var webView: UIWebView!

    var title: String?

    init(title: String?) {
       self.title = title

       self.webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect.zero)
       super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
       commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
       loadSpinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
       loadSpinner.center = webView.center
       view.addSubview(loadSpinner)
       webView.delegate = self
       view = webView
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

`UINavigationController(rootViewController: testWebViewController)`

Even when I try to add the loadSpinner to the webView it does not appear `webView.addSubview(loadSpinner)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Result:
[image]

Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var loadSpinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!
var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))

    loadSpinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)

    webView.addSubview(loadSpinner)

    view = webView

    loadSpinner.startAnimating()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    loadSpinner.center = webView.center
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your primary issue is that you first add the activity indicator to the view controller's view but two lines later you replace the view controller's view with the web view.

If you are going to replace the view controller's view you should do that in `loadView`. You should also setup other views in `viewDidLoad`, not in an `init` method.

The simplest change is to get rid of your `commonInit` method and put all of that code in `viewDidLoad`. Then in `viewDidLoad`, setup the web view first, then setup the activity indicator.

```
class TestWebViewController: UIViewController {
    var loadSpinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    var webView: UIWebView!
    var title: String?

    init(title: String?) {
       self.title = title

       super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    override func loadView() {
        // don't call super

       webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect.zero)
       webView.delegate = self
       view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       loadSpinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
       loadSpinner.center = view.center
       // Keep it in the center
       loadSpinner.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]
       view.addSubview(loadSpinner)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

You also have an issue with `title`. `UIViewController` already has a `title` property. You should not add your own.

Comment: because your load spinner not showing on view. load spinner frame not correct.

Comment: @HalilİbrahimYILMAZ Why not? The web view is set as the view controller's view. It will fill the screen. Then the activity view is set at its center.

Comment: @HalilİbrahimYILMAZ It always was correct. `view` and `webView` are the same view.

Comment: why did you edited text? and you are set view to web view. view.center not correct.

Comment: @HalilİbrahimYILMAZ Why do you keep saying it is incorrect? In what way? `view` and `webView` are the same view. It doesn't matter whether you use `view.center` or `webView.center`. It's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor your code like this inside `viewDidLoad`

```
class TestWebViewController: UIViewController {

    var loadSpinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    var webView: UIWebView!

    var title: String?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView = UIWebView(frame:self.view.frame)

        webView.delegate = self

        self.view.addSubview(webview)

        loadSpinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)

        self.view.addSubview(loadSpinner)

        loadSpinner.center = self.view.center

        loadSpinner.startAnimating()
    }
}
```